# Check the Data if already submit then WAIT for 24 hours

Tags: php, sql, database, forms, cakephp

I built a form for name and URLs using HTML and PHP simple codes. For form validation I used empty and filter_var functions. I want to add some features like

IF name and URL already submitted then wait for 24 hours after time finished then user again submit the form if he wants. This is all done in PHP.

I have an idea that if I check the duplicate data like we check for duplicate username, if taken then we force the user to change username but instead of changing the username here I'll say data already submitted and after 24 hours, if user again want to submit the same data then database remove the old one and user no longer receive the duplicate data error message and again data submit in database.

IS IT possible to do that .? I don't know where to start.

Comment: *Anything* is possible. My Dad has this saying, "If there is an elephant in the room and you have a fork and a knife you can only eat the elephant one bite at a time." Break down all of your requirements into small, bite size chunks and *then* you will have a starting point.

Comment: Great DAD and I get that but still instead of eating the whole elephant alone we can eat together and die together. Thanks for the ti, looking for the starting point here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, you can add datetime into your database when new username is added.
Now select your username and also check if 24 hours have been passed for this username. If you get the result then delete that result from database and insert the new one.

Also instead of deleting the record you can also update whole record for the new user.

I hope i answered your question.

Comment: This is the problem, how can i check if the username passed 24 hours, i mean before time expired i want the user to stop there and show the remaining time . How to put the timer on the specific data .? Where can i put this timer in sql or php and how .?

Comment: If you get record from database where username exist and 24 have not been passed then you can show the remaining time using PHP.

$start = strtotime("3:25");
$stop = time();
$diff = ($stop - $start);
echo $diff/60; //Echoes 65 min